# Adding values based on column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with records of monthly electricity and gas usage of multiple buildings. Some buildings have more than 1 meter and therefore there are 24 records for electricity. I am trying to clean/extract the data and looking for some help on how to add the records if the "RMonth" is the same for 2 entries.

[image]

I am using the following code line to extract the above data:

```
for i in df2['Building ID']:
  row =  df[['RMonth','Consumption']].loc[(df['RYear'] == 2019)& (df['LocName'] == i) & (df['UtilType'] == 'Electric' ) ].transpose()
```

Each building has a different number of meters so I have to test the condition: if "RMonth[0] > 1, then add all entries with "RMonth =1" and "Rmonth = 2" and so on.

Comment: Hi, could you provide an example of the desired output ?

Comment: In the example above, for RMonth = 1, the Consumption should be 232202 +9836. Posting a picture below to show another record that is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I want. So if there are 2 entries for RMonth, they should be added.
[image]